# Probability -> Knowing that $P(A) \cdot P(B) = 0.05$ calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Tags: probability

Events $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $P(A)>P(B)$, and $\Omega = A \cup B$. Knowing that $P(A) \cdot P(B) = 0.05$ calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: $[\Omega=A\cup B]\wedge[A\text{ and }B\text{ are disjoint events}]\implies P(A)+P(B)=1$. From here onwards, it's simply a system of $2$ equations in $2$ variables: $[P(A)+P(B)=1]\text{ and }[P(A)\times P(B)=0.05]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. $P(A)+P(B)=1$
2. $P(A)P(B)=0.05$

this gives that they are both solutions to the equation $x^2-x+1/20=0$ which gives $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: It looks like you meant 
$$x^2 - x \color{red}{-} \frac{1}{20} = 0$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, :$$(x-P(A))(x-P(B))=x^2-(P(A)+P(B))x+P(A)P(B)=x^2-x+\frac{1}{20}$$

Comment: I thought you meant $P(A) = x$ and $P(B) = 1 - x$.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the same :$x(1-x)=0.05$ then $x-x^2=\frac{1}{20}$ so $x^2-x+\frac{1}{20}=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$
[P(A)+P(B)]^2=P(A)^2+2P(A)P(B)+P(B)^2=1\Rightarrow P(A)^2+P(B)^2=0.9
$$

Similarly

$$
[P(A)-P(B)]^2=P(A)^2-2P(A)P(B)+P(B)^2=0.8\Rightarrow P(A)-P(B)=\sqrt{\frac{8}{10}}
$$

This gives $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{8}{10}}$